# Как закрыть доступ к расширению в yii2 для frontend

Tags: yii2

yii2-advanced, есть расширение yii2-mod/rbac, доступно по адресу `*host/rbac*`.

Мне нужно закрыть доступ к нему и оставить только доступ через backend, `*host/admin/rbac*`., для аккаунтов с нужными правами

Есть такой вариант: изменить правило роутинга, тогда страницы по адресу `rbac` не будет существовать, и никто из тех, у кого нет разрешения на ее просмотр, не сможет получить к ней доступ:

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'rules' => [
            '/rbac' => '/admin/rbac'
        ],
    ],
],
```

... но к `/admin/rbac` имеют доступ все. Нужно закрыть его для всех тех, у кого нету привилегий.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В common\main\config вставить такие строчки:

```
'modules' => [
    'rbac' => [
        'class' => 'yii2mod\rbac\Module',
        'as access' => [
            'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['admin'] //любые другие роли и правила
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

и все заработает